# setting mdButton attributes conditionally

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

As it is asked, I want to set button highlighted using accent color when it is active..

Something like

```
<button md-button *ngFor="let item of items" [attr.color]="item.caption == activeItem ? 'accent' : ''">
```

or perhaps something like

```
<button md-button *ngFor="let item of items" color="{{ item.activeColor }}"
```

I seem to be able to do it that way in Angular 1, but doesn't have effect in Angular 2.

Can someone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to set `color` same as below as `color` is `@Input` property as per [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/component/button) :

```
<button md-button *ngFor="let item of items" [color]="item.caption ==  activeItem ? 'accent' : ''">
```